# Extern for dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, socket.io, haxe

I'm trying to upgrade the Socket.IO [extern](https://github.com/clemos/haxe-js-kit/blob/master/js/npm/socketio/Namespace.hx) and I'm facing a problem.

So far, to set a variable, they used

```
socket.set(key, val, callback);
```

But now it's

```
socket.key = val;
```

(see the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1515))

---

How am I supposed to reflect this behaviour in Haxe?

Any leads will be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an inline function:

```
public inline function set(key : String, value : Dynamic)  
  Reflect.setField(this, key, value);
```

Comment: Like [this](http://try.haxe.org/#B5E8E)? This looks well for the setter but I'd like to change the syntax as little as possible. Someone on IRC told me I could implement Dynamic, or use a macro to generate those fields on the field. I don't know which one is the best

Comment: Have you tried the "implement Dynamic" one? That sounds like the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I'm filling like I'm wasting the Haxe typing system. But maybe it can't be helped

Comment: I don't think you'd get many benefits from the Haxe typing system anyway, given that you're storing Dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the "[using](http://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html)" keyword.

```
class SocketExtender {
    public static inline function set(socket:Socket, key:String, value:Dynamic):Void {
        Reflect.setField(socket, key, value);
    }
    public static inline function get(socket:Socket, key:String):Dynamic {
        Reflect.field(socket, key);
    }
}
```

Then add "`using com.my.package.SocketExtender;`" by your imports, and your code should start working again.

Comment: That's kind of the same as Franco's answer, but I would have to write another class. Since I can write in class Socket directly, I'm not sure how using is helping

Comment: Oh, I guess I misinterpreted your post. You're willing to change all the places that you wrote `set(...)`, but you'd like to change them to the "correct" syntax (`socket.x = y`), and you're not sure how to make the latter work. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly right! My goal is to "copy" NodeJS syntax so useres can switch to Haxe almost without changing their code